# BASH to BATCH java

Tags: java, bash, batch-file

There's this BASH file:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eu
DIR=`dirname $0`
JAR=$DIR/myjar.jar
CLASSPATH=$JAR:./
HEAP_SIZE=-size
java $HEAP_SIZE -cp $CLASSPATH something.something2 "$@"
```

That I want to turn into a .bat file to run on windows
This is what I have so far:

```
@ECHO OFF
set DIR = %cd%
set JAR = DIR/myjar.jar
set CLASSPATH = %JAR%:./
set HEAP_SIZE = -size
java %HEAP_SIZE% -cp %CLASSPATH% something.something2
```

How would I complete it to have the same behavior as the bash file?

Answer (score 4):

`%CD%` can work, but your bash script seems to be setting the directory based off the path of the script (i.e., argument in `$0`) and not the current directory.  To use the same directory as the batch file, you use `%~dp0`.

You missed `%` around your `DIR` variable when you wanted to expand the value.

You shouldn't have spaces around equal signs in your `set` statements.

The equivalent of `$@` in batch is `%*`.

You should quote your `%CLASSPATH%`.  On Windows you are much more likely to encounter paths with spaces in them.

```
@ECHO OFF
set "DIR=%~dp0"
set "JAR=%DIR%/myjar.jar"
set "CLASSPATH=%JAR%:./"
set "HEAP_SIZE=-size"
java %HEAP_SIZE% -cp "%CLASSPATH%" something.something2 %*
```